# Prove $\sqrt{a_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{L}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $(a_n) \rightarrow L, a_n > 0, \forall n \in \mathrm N, and L > 0$, then how can I show $\sqrt{a_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{L}$?

I am given this hint, but I am not sure what to do with it:
$\forall n \in \mathrm N, \sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L} > \sqrt{L}$.

Would I just be able to say that as we take the sqaure root of each $a_n$, the sequence value is also a the square root?

Any help would be great, because I am very confused and lost.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for an $\epsilon-N$ proof. The hint is suggesting you do something with the difference $| \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}|$, i.e., 'rationalize' it

$$ | \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}| = \frac{ |a_n - L|}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}}$$

Now, given an $\epsilon > 0$, what choice of $N$ will give you the desired implication?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $$\forall n \in \mathrm N, \sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}\geq \sqrt{L}$$ since you could have $(a_n)=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}| = \dfrac{|a_n-L|}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}} < \dfrac{|a_n-L|}{\sqrt{L}}$.

Thus for a given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that for if $n > N \Rightarrow |a_n-L| < \epsilon\cdot \sqrt{L} \Rightarrow \dfrac{|a_n-L|}{\sqrt{L}} < \epsilon \Rightarrow |\sqrt{a_n} -\sqrt{L}| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for an $\epsilon-N$ proof. The hint is suggesting you do something with the difference $| \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}|$, i.e., 'rationalize' it

$$ \left| \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}\right| = \frac{ |a_n - L|}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} |a_n - L|$$

Now, given an $\epsilon > 0$, what choice of $N$ will give you the desired implication?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the fact that $\sqrt x$  is continuous in $( 0, \infty)$, so that it is sequentially continuous, i.e., if $f$ is continuous then $x_n \rightarrow x $ then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.